Recompiling early FMX application in latest Delphi
I have an old (2016) source code for a Delphi Android FMX application. I want to rebuild it in Delphi 11.3 but there is a problem.
(my other projects can be built and deployed correctly, so Delphi is configured well, the problem is only in this one application)
Checking project dependencies...
Building nz.dproj (Debug, Android)
brcc32 command line for "nz.vrc"
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\cgrc.exe -c65001 nz.vrc -fonz.res 
dccaarm command line for "nz.dpr"
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\dccaarm.exe -$O- --no-config -B -Q -TX.so -AGenerics.Collections=System.Generics.Collections;
  Generics.Defaults=System.Generics.Defaults -DDEBUG;;FRAMEWORK_FMX -E.\Android\Debug -I"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Android\debug";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Android\Release";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Dcp\Android;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\UniDAC for RAD Studio 11\Lib\Android32" 
  -LEC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Bpl\Android -LNC:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Dcp\Android -NU.\Android\Debug 
  -NSSystem;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap; -O"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Android\Release";
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Dcp\Android;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\UniDAC for RAD Studio 11\Lib\Android32" -R"c:\program 
  files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Android\Release";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Dcp\Android;"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Devart\UniDAC for RAD Studio 11\Lib\Android32" -U"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Android\debug";"c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\Android\Release";C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Dcp\Android;"C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Devart\UniDAC for RAD Studio 11\Lib\Android32" 
  --libpath:C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.48361.3236\android-ndk-r21\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\libs\armeabi-v7a;
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.48361.3236\android-ndk-r21\platforms\android-23\arch-arm\usr\lib 
  --linker:C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-22.0.48361.3236\android-ndk-r21\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe 
  -V -VN -NO.\Android\Debug  nz.dpr   
[DCC Hint] special.pas(16): H2164 Variable 'ms2' is declared but never used in 'LoadBitmapFromBlob'
[DCC Hint] main.pas(128): H2164 Variable 'index' is declared but never used in 'TForm1.ListBoxPolItemClick'
paclient command line
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 --dexmerge="C:\Program Files\Eclipse 
  Adoptium\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe,c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\Android\r8-3.3.28.jar,C:\PROJEKTY\NZ\6\Android\Debug\nz.classes,23,C:\PROJEKTY\NZ\6\Android\Debug\dex_list.txt"  
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Unable to execute '"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -cp "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\Android\r8-3.3.28.jar" com.android.tools.r8.D8 --release --min-api 23 --output "C:\PROJEKTY\NZ\6\Android\Debug\nz.classes" @"C:\PROJEKTY\NZ\6\Android\Debug\dex_list.txt"' (Error 1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Error in c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar:
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Error in c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar:
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Compilation failed with an internal error.
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:98)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:4)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.28.java:0)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:75)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:28)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:27)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.build(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:2)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:4)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:85)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   ... 1 more
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.utils.j$a.d(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:21)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.e(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:3)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:12)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.addProgramFiles(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:3)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.addProgramFiles(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.n.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1058)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.n.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   at com.android.tools.r8.D8Command.parse(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   ... 3 more
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.internal.DT.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:25)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:3)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:24)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.build(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:2)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       ... 3 more
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.internal.DT.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:14)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.internal.DT.error(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.j$a.d(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:22)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.e(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:3)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:12)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.addProgramFiles(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:3)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.BaseCommand$Builder.addProgramFiles(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.n.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1058)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.n.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       at com.android.tools.r8.D8Command.parse(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688       ... 3 more
[PAClient Error] Error: E7688   Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar]
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:09.3*


Did you try revert system files to default? Projects window \ Target Platforms \ Android 32 or 64, right click on Libraries and choose Revert System Files to Default.

Revert option is disabled in this menu

Ok, Revert Libaries helps

The release notes for 12 Athens includes the following when upgrading Android applications:

Android 30 API support
The new releases include a different set of Java libraries, which makes old projects incompatible. When you open an Android project built with an older version of RAD Studio, you need to:

Navigate to the Projects dockable window.
Select Android 32-bit or Android 64-bit as the active target platform.
Right-click on the Libraries node.
Click on the Revert System Files to Default menu item.


If you don't see the Projects window use [Ctrl][Alt]+[F11] to bring it up.

That should get you started. You also need to delete the AndroidManifest.template.xml, but be aware that if you customized it you will need to migrate the customizations.
